# force close application

Tags: android, json, jsp, android-layout

when i click on the login button my application force closes...why is it??? what is the solution for this?

I have my Login_Menu activity as follows:-

```
package com.campuspro.start;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Login_Menu extends Activity {

EditText usname;
EditText pass;
TextView tv;
HttpClient client;
HttpPost post;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login_lay);
 tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_stat_tv);
 usname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.uname);
 pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
Button login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_but);
Button cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_but);

client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url="http://10.0.2.2:7001/proj/login.jsp";
post = new HttpPost(url);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new login().execute("");
    }
});

cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        usname.getText().clear();
        pass.getText().clear();
    }
});

 }


 private class login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{
 ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login_Menu.this, "", "Authenticating,    Please wait...");

  @Override
  protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("thread", "Doing Something...");
   //authentication operation
try{

    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();   
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",usname.getText().toString()));   
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString()));   
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));   
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    int status=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if(status == 200)
    {
        HttpEntity e=response.getEntity();
        String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject last=new JSONObject(data);
        return last;

    }

}

 catch(Exception e)
 {
     e.printStackTrace();   

 }

    return null;
 }

 protected void onPreExecute(){
    //dialog.dismiss();
    Log.i("thread", "Started...");
    dialog.show();
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
    Log.i("thread", "Done...");
    String name;
    try {
        name = result.getString("status");

    if(dialog!=null)
    dialog.dismiss();
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        tv.setText("user found");
        Intent myIntent=new Intent("com.campuspro.start.MYMENU");
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }else{

    tv.setText("No User Found, please try again!");
    }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}}
```

My login.jsp page is as follows...

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
 <%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>

 <%!

 Connection con;
 PreparedStatement ps;
 ResultSet rs;
 String x,y;

 %>

 <%
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","pro","pro");
 x=request.getParameter("username");
 y=request.getParameter("password");

 ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from login_stud where uname=? and pass=?");
 ps.setString(1,x);
 ps.setString(2,y);
 rs=ps.executeQuery();

JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
if(rs.next())
{
obj.put("status","yes");
out.print(obj);

}
else
{
obj.put("status","no");
out.print(obj);
}
out.flush();
 %>
```

This is my log cat....

```
 04-15 23:42:06.449: I/thread(276): Started...
 04-15 23:42:06.460: I/thread(276): Doing Something...
 04-15 23:42:07.950: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3284 objects / 170544 bytes   in 156ms
 04-15 23:42:10.469: I/thread(276): Done...
 04-15 23:42:10.469: D/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM
 04-15 23:42:10.469: W/dalvikvm(276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at    com.campuspro.start.Login_Menu$login.onPostExecute(Login_Menu.java:117)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at      com.campuspro.start.Login_Menu$login.onPostExecute(Login_Menu.java:1)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 04-15 23:42:10.509: E/AndroidRuntime(276):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the stacktrace shows a line number, look there for your error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app was force closing because the MYMENU activity was not mentioned in Android manifest file.

There was no such error in starting the intent.

The procedure to declare an activity in androidmanifest.xml is:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.campuspro.start.ACTIVITYNAME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This is the root cause:

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent("com.campuspro.start.MYMENU");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

It should be something like:

```
Intent myIntent=new Intent(Login_Menu.this, MYMENU.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```